# Deleting 3 lines of code every 4

Tags: regular-expression

I want to sort my database by regex, but don't know exactly how to do it.

The editor I use is Atom

It's example of input (the entire file has 10,000 lines)

```
x1.83
30.12.2018, 12:05:29
1386834
30
x2.66
30.12.2018, 12:05:01
1386833
30
x2.12
30.12.2018, 12:04:36
1386832
30
x2.51
30.12.2018, 12:04:09
1386831
30
x2.19
30.12.2018, 12:03:44
1386830
30
x1.04
30.12.2018, 12:03:31
1386829
30
x4.18
```

What I want, as a output:

```
x1.83
x2.66
x2.12
x2.51
x2.19
x1.04
x4.18
```

Can someone help me with this ?

**P.S.** On the other hand - is it possible to copy values from specific class by chrome inspector ?

Comment: cat myfile | grep x     :-) or   cat my file | grep ^x

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what to do with this. I'm using this tool for regex:
https://imgur.com/a/yyZ9aGy

Comment: This site is for Vim questions. Are you just trying to print every fourth line? Try `awk '{ if ((NR-1) % 4 ==  0) print; }'`. Or every line with pattern "x#.##"? Try `awk '/^x[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$/ { print; }'`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as written, this editing task concerns the Atom editor and not vi/vim.

Comment: @TheUnixJanitor `grep x file`, no useless cats ;)

Comment: Should be closed as off topic as it targets Atom, not Vi/Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Vim way

Basically, you are trying to delete lines which starts with numbers and to select only those lines you can use a simple regex like this: `^\d.\+$`

You can find the matches by prefixing the regex with a `/`, i.e, `/^\d.\+$`. This will only match the lines starting with a number, you can delete those lines with

```
:g/^\d.\+$/d
```

This will produce your preferred output. For more info see `:help :global` and `:help pattern.txt`

In command line you can directly do this without opening vim:

```
vim datafile -es +"g/^\d.\+$/d" +"w\! new_datafile" +"qa\!"
```

#### Other ways

`sed` way : `sed -nre '/^x[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/p' datafile`
`grep` way: `grep -v "^[0-9].*$" datafile`
`awk` way : `awk '/^x[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/' datafile`
`perl` way: `perl -ne "print if /^x[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/" datafile`

To save it I usually redirect the output to a new file ( there is also in-place editing mode you can check ), like this `cmd > new_datafile`

Comment: Thank you very much, it made my work a lot easier.

For others -  In Atom you have to write this: ^\d.+$